# TextView Scale property in android

Tags: android, textview, imageview, scale

Is there a TextView equivalent to the following statement `v.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);`

The code I'm using it in is...

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    mParentView = parent;

    ImageCell v = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // If it's not recycled, create a new ImageCell.
        v = new ImageCell (mContext);
        v.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        //   v.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        v.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

    } else {
        v = (ImageCell) convertView;
    }

    v.mCellNumber = position;
    v.mGrid = (GridView) mParentView;
    v.mEmpty = true;
    //    v.setBackgroundResource (R.color.drop_target_enabled);
    v.setBackgroundResource (R.color.cell_empty);

    //v.mGrid.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent (true);

    //v.setImageResource (R.drawable.hello);

    // Set up to relay events to the activity.
    // The activity decides which events trigger drag operations.
    // Activities like the Android Launcher require a long click to get a drag operation started.
    v.setOnTouchListener ((View.OnTouchListener) mContext);
    v.setOnClickListener ((View.OnClickListener) mContext);
    v.setOnLongClickListener ((View.OnLongClickListener) mContext);

    return v;
}
```

The code is meant for `ImageView`. I want to convert it to `TextView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot set scaleType for a TextView. What is stopping you from using an Imageview? Also FYI scaleType is not applicable for background image of an ImageView.

Comment: I need Some text to be displayed over my image

Comment: Is there a way to put text in an Image View

Comment: No. If it is not a dynamically changing text, you can put text on image itself and use it in ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this
     tvBack.scaleX = -1f

Comment: Looks more like a comment than answer.